# IFrame Local Storage Name has additional Suffix "^0<parent domain url>" in Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, browser, local-storage, suffix

I've encountered an strange behavior in Chrome
related to the local storage url naming that the browser decides.

I've noticed that the local storage name inside an iframe has a suffix "^0" followed by the domain of the parent URL.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVjy1.png)

This behavior doesn't seem to be consistent when it happens on a certain computer
but if I create another user on the same computer same chrome version the issue is not reproduced
and I've checked extensions and other configurations and didn't find any clues why this suffix is being added

I've tried as well on a computer that had this issue
to update to the latest chrome version
116.0.5845.97
the issue disappeared
previously the version was something like this:
115.x.xxxx.170

I'm seeking to understand why this happens
and whether there's a way to control this behavior.

Comment: Why does it matter to you? That's not like something scripts can interact with. What do you want to do with this name?

Comment: @Kaiido 
this behavior creates an issue in the following scenario
you load the application (lets call it X) in chrome as the primary url 
providing query params and injecting it into the local storage

when application Y is loaded it loads X in iframe
application X doesn't have access to the same local storage as it had when loaded as the main url

Main url local storage name - https://x.net
iframe url local storage name - https://x.net^0https://y.net

Comment: @Kaiido
by the way I am not seeking for a script to interact with it

from the questions 
I'm seeking to understand why this happens and whether there's a way to control this behavior.

controlling it means by user interaction as this is a behavior that sometimes happens and sometimes not for unknown reason

Comment: Then show us how you load the iframe (including HTTP headers) and how the localStorage is accessed.

Comment: @Kaiido
this happens in all iframes when using chrome
you can check any url that has iframes in it using chrome
for example this one
https://www.programiz.com/html/iframe

I got another picture on another computer where it happens on other sites just had this one in hand for the question as I wasn't able to find any documentation in chrome how it decides the storage name and when it decides to add this suffix

forgot to mention in addition a test I've done is when this happens it doesn't happen on any other browsers only on chrome the other tests you can read in my question

Comment: @Kaiido found the reason why it happened
new feature by chrome being slowly released for certain users soon to be released to all users

https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the reason chrome starting to role out a new feature
details can be found here
https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/